# Totality checker stumbles on (S k) > k

Tags: recursion, idris, termination

I've defined a stack machine that push numbers, push functions and evaluate functions. To make things total I have given the ASM instructions an universe `(u : Nat)` and a `n`-universe function can only be pushed and called by a `S n`-universe function. Thus `eval` should be total if I'm not wrong - but the totality checker doesn't see this. Surprising is that adding `assert_smaller (S k) k` on the recursive `eval` call helps. Do I miss something? An example that doesn't compile is the following. I tried also to combine `eval` and `eval'` into one function.

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.HVect

data Ty : Type where
  TyInt : Ty 
  TyFun : (u : Nat) -> (prev : Vect n Ty) -> (post : Vect m Ty) -> Ty

mutual
  data ASM : (u : Nat) -> (prev : Vect n Ty) -> (post : Vect m Ty) -> Type where
    PushInt : (i : Int) -> ASM u s (TyInt :: s)
    Fun : (f : Instructions u a b) -> ASM (S u) s (TyFun u a b :: s)
    Eval : (u : Nat) -> ASM (S u) (TyFun u s b :: s) b

  data Instructions : Nat -> Vect n Ty -> Vect m Ty -> Type where
    Nil : Instructions u n n
    (::) : ASM u n m -> Instructions u m p -> Instructions u n p 

tyType : Ty -> Type
tyType TyInt = Int
tyType (TyFun u a b) = Instructions u a b

tyTypes : Vect n Ty -> Vect n Type
tyTypes [] = []
tyTypes (x :: xs) = (tyType x :: tyTypes xs)

mutual 
  eval' : ASM u s n -> HVect (tyTypes s) -> HVect (tyTypes n)
  eval' (PushInt x) xs = (x :: xs)
  eval' {u=S k} (Fun f) xs = (f :: xs)
  eval' {u=S k} (Eval k) (f :: xs) = eval {u=k} f xs
  --eval' {u=S k} (Eval k) (f :: xs) = eval {u=assert_smaller (S k) k} f xs

  eval : Instructions u a b -> HVect (tyTypes a) -> HVect (tyTypes b)
  eval [] xs = xs
  eval (i :: is) xs = eval is (eval' i xs)
```